# LINQ to SQL separation and reusability of data structures

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0, reusability

Here is simplified SQL of my tables, which is converted to LINQ to SQL model.

```
CREATE TABLE Campaign (
    Id int PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE Contract (
    Id int PRIMARY KEY,
    CampaignId int NULL REFERENCES Campaign(Id)
);
```

Now i have classes like this (**these are in different namespace, not entity classes from datamodel**).

```
public class CampaignInfo {
    public static CampaignModel Get(DataModel.CampaignInfo campaign) {
         return new CampaignInfo {
              Id = campaign.Id,
              Name = campaign.Name,
              Status = CampaignStatus.Get( c )
         };
    }
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Name {get; set;}
    public CampaignStatus { get; set;}
}

public class CampaignStatus {
    public static CampaignStatus Get(DataModel.Campaign campaign) {
         return new CampaignStatus {
              Campaign = campaign.Id, // this is just for lookup on client side
              ContractCount = campaign.Contracts.Count()
              // There is much more fields concerning status of campaign
         };
    }
    public int Campaign { get; set; }
    public int ContractCount {get; set;}
}
```

And than i am running query:

```
dataContext.Campaigns.Select( c => CampaignInfo.Get( c ) );
```

Other piece of code can do something like this:

```
dataContext.Campaigns.Where( c => c.Name == "DoIt" ).Select( c => CampaignInfo.Get( c ) );
```

Or i want to get list of statuses for campaigns:

```
dataContext.Campaigns.Select( c => CampaignStatus.Get( c ) );
```

*Note: Results from those calls are converted to JSON, so there is no need to keep track on original db entities.*

As you can see, there are two goals. To have control over what data are taken from database and reuse those structures in other places. However this approach is a huge mistake, because of that classes returning object and using it in expression tree.

Now i understand, it cannot magically create expression to make whole thing with one query. Instead it's getting count for every campaign separately. In rather complex scenarios it's ugly slowdown.

Is there some simple way how to achieve this ? I guess, those classes should return some expressions, but i am totally new to this field and i am not sure what to do.

Comment: I think, i had figured out part of this. Using pastebin for now, so it's not getting too long here. http://pastebin.com/rttTgxyJ. Instead of object, i am returning `Expression<Func<Campaign, CampaignStatus>>`. However i cannot figure out how to wrap CampaignStatus with CampaignInfo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general problem, if I understand correctly, is that you have some business logic that you don't want to have repeated throughout your code (DRY). You want to be able to use this logic inside your LINQ methods.

The general solution with LINQ (over Expression trees) is to create a filter or transformation function that returns an `IQueryable` so you can do further processing on that query, before it is sent to the database.

Here is a way to do this:

```
// Reusable method that returns a query of CampaignStatus objects
public static IQueryable<CampaignStatus> 
    GetCampaignStatusses(this IQueryable<Compaign> campaigns)
{
    return
        from campaign in campaigns
        new CampaignStatus
        {
            Campaign = campaign.Id,
            ContractCount = compaign.Contracts.Count()
        };
}
```

With this in place, you can write the following code:

```
using (var db = new DataModel.ModelDataContext() ) 
{
    return
        from campaign in db.Campaigns.WithContractCount()
        from status in db.Campaigns.GetCampaignStatusses()
        where campaign.Id == status.Campaign
        select new
        {
            Id = campaign.Id,
            Name = campaign.Name,
            Status = status
        };
}
```

Having an method that returns an `IQueryable` allows you to do all sorts of extra operations, without that method knowing about it. For instance, you can add filtering:

```
        from campaign in db.Campaigns.WithContractCount()
        from status in db.Campaigns.GetCampaignStatusses()
        where campaign.Id == status.Campaign
        where campaign .Name == "DoIt"
        where status .ContractsCount < 10
        select new
        {
            Id = campaign.Id,
            Name = campaign.Name,
            Status = status
        };
```

or add extra properties to the output:

```
        from campaign in db.Campaigns.WithContractCount()
        from status in db.Campaigns.GetCampaignStatusses()
        where campaign.Id == status.Campaign
        select new
        {
            OtherProp = campaign.OtherProp,
            Id = status.Campaign,

            Name = campaign.Name,
            Status = status
        };
```

This will be translated to an efficient SQL query. The query will not get more records or columns from the database than strictly needed.

Comment: Thanks, but either i don't understand or it's not what i am looking for. There will be definitely more fields in `CampaignStatus` and i want to reuse that `Campaign` class too. I had updated question to more examples.

Comment: @FredyC: I updated my answer. I still think this is what you need.

Comment: I am still missing one part there. You are putting just one variable to the Status property, but i need more of them there. Or to be more specific. I need that Status object as whole and to be part of Campaign or to be able standalone.

Comment: @FredyC: In my example I initialize 2 properties. You can add more if you like. The trick is to do this initialization *inside* a LINQ (IQueryable) query and reuse that query throughout the application. That is the way to be able to reuse that logic inside other LINQ queries.

Comment: Sorry, but i still don't see it there. When i say "give me `Status`", it needs to have fixed structure for `Status`. When i say "give me `Campaign`", it needs to have `Campaign` information with exact same `Status` structure inside of it. I don't need to be configurable. Those are models for MVC, it needs to have same structure always...Something like this: http://pastebin.com/Sa5v9cfL

Comment: I'll say it other way. You have there method `WithContractCount`. That should be more like `CampaignWithStatus`. Campaign will have always info about it's status, however status can act alone, because i need to read that periodically from server without info about campaign itself. Other words, Status contains data changing in time. And this is part i don't understand. How to ripoff that Status so i can reuse it elsewhere with same structure.

Comment: @FredyC: I see what you mean. I'm not familiar with JSON serialization, but I think you can just assign the `CampaignStatus` object to the `Status` property of the anonymous type. Also see my newest update. I simplified the extension method (now called `GetCampaignStatusses`) and changed the queries in such way that I think fir your question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4720/discussion-between-fredyc-and-steven)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
using( var dataContext = new DataModel.ModelDataContext() )  
{  
    dataContext.Campaigns.Select( c => new {  
            Id = c.Id,  
            Name = c.Name,  
            Status = new CampaignStatus()  
            {  
                ContractCount = c.Contracts.Count()  
            }  
        })  
}
```

in your query.

Comment: That's exactly what don't want to, because of reusability :) In some other code i want to get just status for campaign. There is more properties in `ContractStatus`, this is just short version.